# How to perform operations on VSCode macros?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My `launch.json` specifies a list of arguments for a given debug session (For airflow debugging in this case):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "airflow_debug",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/airflow",
            "preLaunchTask": "activate-python-venv",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "AIRFLOW_HOME": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES": "False",
                "AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER": "${workspaceFolder}/dags",
                "AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR": "SequentialExecutor",
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/plugins:${workspaceFolder}/dags:${env:PYTHONPATH}"
            },
            "args": [
                "dags",
                "test",
                "migrate_dtm",
                "2022-11-24"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to be able to debug my dags, I must specify the dag name in the `args`, here it is `migrate_dtm`. A more sophisticated way, would be to **deduce** the name of the dag from the name of the file My file's name is `migrate_dtm_dag.py`.

The goal here is not to change the `launch.json` and manually specify the dag name within every different debug launch; but only set a nomenclature rule for the devs to follow.

Something like this would help

```
"args":[
        ...
        "${file.split('/')[-1].split('_dag')'}",  // First split to get only the file name without the path, second split to extract the dag name.
        ...
]
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this in a VSCode macro? Or to perform operations on macros at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "airflow_debug",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/airflow",
            "preLaunchTask": "activate-python-venv",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "AIRFLOW_HOME": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES": "False",
                "AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER": "${workspaceFolder}/dags",
                "AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR": "SequentialExecutor",
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/plugins:${workspaceFolder}/dags:${env:PYTHONPATH}"
            },
            "args": [
                "dags",
                "test",
                "${input:getdag}",
                "2022-11-24"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
          "id": "getdag",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
          "args": {
              "text": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
              "find": "_dag"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

The default replace is `""`, so it removed the text `_dag`.

With the command [`extension.commandvariable.dateTime`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#datetime) you can create a date string for today.